# CodeIgniter 2.0.3 Pagination Class starting page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, numbers

I was trying to work with the codeigniter pagination class.

Here is my code

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = base_url('language/'.$this->uri->segment(2));
$config['total_rows'] = $page_count;
$config['per_page'] = 1; 
$config['num_links'] = '2';
$config['uri_segment'] = '2';

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$data['pages'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

but then, in the first page, the url would be look like

```
localhost/language/something/
```

while the second page would be

```
localhost/language/something/1
```

which looks kinda weird, is it possible to have the url starts with 1 on first page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to override the built in pagination class. Place it in application/libraries and just do everything else like normal.

I've added a comment to each line I edited from the original class.

NOTE: in your sample code you put total pages in the total_rows config value. Be sure to put the total number of records, not the total number of pages.

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Pagination extends CI_Pagination {

  function create_links()
  {
    // If our item count or per-page total is zero there is no need to continue.
    if ($this->total_rows == 0 OR $this->per_page == 0)
    {
      return '';
    }

    // Calculate the total number of pages
    $num_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->per_page);

    // Is there only one page? Hm... nothing more to do here then.
    if ($num_pages == 1)
    {
      return '';
    }

    // Determine the current page number.
    $CI =& get_instance();

    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
      if ($CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment) != 0)
      {
        $this->cur_page = $CI->input->get($this->query_string_segment);

        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if ($CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment) != 0)
      {
        $this->cur_page = $CI->uri->segment($this->uri_segment);

        // Prep the current page - no funny business!
        $this->cur_page = (int) $this->cur_page;
      }
    }

    $this->num_links = (int)$this->num_links;

    if ($this->num_links < 1)
    {
      show_error('Your number of links must be a positive number.');
    }

    if ( ! is_numeric($this->cur_page) || $this->cur_page < 1) // EDITED
    {
      $this->cur_page = 1; // EDITED
    }

    // Is the page number beyond the result range?
    // If so we show the last page
    if (($this->cur_page * $this->per_page) > $this->total_rows) // EDITED
    {
      $this->cur_page = ($num_pages - 1); // EDITED
    }

    $uri_page_number = $this->cur_page;
    //$this->cur_page = floor(($this->cur_page/$this->per_page) + 1); // EDITED

    // Calculate the start and end numbers. These determine
    // which number to start and end the digit links with
    $start = (($this->cur_page - $this->num_links) > 0) ? $this->cur_page - ($this->num_links - 1) : 1;
    $end   = (($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages) ? $this->cur_page + $this->num_links : $num_pages;

    // Is pagination being used over GET or POST?  If get, add a per_page query
    // string. If post, add a trailing slash to the base URL if needed
    if ($CI->config->item('enable_query_strings') === TRUE OR $this->page_query_string === TRUE)
    {
      $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url).'&amp;'.$this->query_string_segment.'=';
    }
    else
    {
      $this->base_url = rtrim($this->base_url, '/') .'/';
    }

    // And here we go...
    $output = '';

    // Render the "First" link
    if  ($this->first_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page > ($this->num_links)) // EDITED
    {
      $first_url = ($this->first_url == '') ? $this->base_url : $this->first_url;
      $output .= $this->first_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$first_url.'">'.$this->first_link.'</a>'.$this->first_tag_close;
    }

    // Render the "previous" link
    if  ($this->prev_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page != 1)
    {
      $i = $this->cur_page-1; // EDITED

      if ($i == 1 && $this->first_url != '') // EDITED
      {
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
      }
      else
      {
        $i = ($i == 1) ? '' : $this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix; // EDITED
        $output .= $this->prev_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$i.'">'.$this->prev_link.'</a>'.$this->prev_tag_close;
      }

    }

    // Render the pages
    if ($this->display_pages !== FALSE)
    {
      // Write the digit links
      for ($loop = $start; $loop <= $end; $loop++)
      {
        $i = $loop; // EDITED

        if ($i >= 0)
        {
          if ($this->cur_page == $loop)
          {
            $output .= $this->cur_tag_open.$loop.$this->cur_tag_close; // Current page
          }
          else
          {
            $n = ($i == 0) ? '' : $i;

            if ($n == '' && $this->first_url != '')
            {
              $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->first_url.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
            }
            else
            {
              $n = ($n == '') ? '' : $this->prefix.$n.$this->suffix;

              $output .= $this->num_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$n.'">'.$loop.'</a>'.$this->num_tag_close;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // Render the "next" link
    if ($this->next_link !== FALSE AND $this->cur_page < $num_pages)
    {
      $output .= $this->next_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.($this->cur_page+1).$this->suffix.'">'.$this->next_link.'</a>'.$this->next_tag_close; // EDITED
    }

    // Render the "Last" link
    if ($this->last_link !== FALSE AND ($this->cur_page + $this->num_links) < $num_pages)
    {
      $i = $num_pages; // EDITED
      $output .= $this->last_tag_open.'<a '.$this->anchor_class.'href="'.$this->base_url.$this->prefix.$i.$this->suffix.'">'.$this->last_link.'</a>'.$this->last_tag_close;
    }

    // Kill double slashes.  Note: Sometimes we can end up with a double slash
    // in the penultimate link so we'll kill all double slashes.
    $output = preg_replace("#([^:])//+#", "\\1/", $output);

    // Add the wrapper HTML if exists
    $output = $this->full_tag_open.$output.$this->full_tag_close;

    return $output;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The number in the URL is not the page number, it is the record offset.

For example, if you set it to 25 records per page:

```
$config['per_page'] = 25;
```

The URL for page 1 would be this:

```
localhost/language/something/
```

and page 2 would be this:

```
localhost/language/something/25
```

and page 3...

```
localhost/language/something/50
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but is it possible to change that instead of showing the offset, shows the current page instead?

Comment: You'll need to extend (inherit) the Pagination library. If you tell me which version of CI you're using, I'll post the code.

Comment: I'm using the latest one, which should be 2.0.3

Comment: @Jonathan Chow if you want to show page numbers in the URI instead of index you can set the config:

$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;

Comment: that is a new feature added in CodeIgniter 2.1 :)