# Codeigniter, setting up pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, i'm having a problem to setting up pagination on my site.

First of all, if i'm at the first page of my site, and pressing to go to page 2, the "1" still stays bold. Though i can see in the url that i am at page 2.

Secondly, i need some help to retrieve the data correctly. If i am at page 1, i want to get all records 1-10. If i am on page 2, i want to get all records from 11-20. Got it?

I have google'd and tried to find any solution, without any success.

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('comments');
$this->db->where('comments.url_friendly', $id);
$this->db->join('allt', 'allt.url_friendly = comments.url_friendly', 'left');
$this->db->order_by('comments.date', 'asc');
$data['query'] = $this->db->get();

$data['title'] = 'Kommentarer - '.$data['query']->row()->amne;

$config['base_url'] = base_url(). 'kommentarer/'.$data['query']->row()->url_friendly;
$config['total_rows'] = $data['query']->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 10;

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

Also, i'm using the code in post 2, in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666254/codeigniter-2-0-3-pagination-class-starting-page).

And yes, i'm new to Codeigniter, as you can see.

Comment: There is a ton wrong with the way that code is laid out. You have controller and model functions mixed in there. Read this: http://phpmaster.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$qry = "select * from comment c left join allt a on c.url_friendly = a.url_friendly where c.url_friendly = {$id}";

$per_page = 10;
$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3):0);//this will get the current page(assuming that page number is in 3rd uri segment). if youy on page one,this will be set to zero

$config['base_url'] = base_url(). 'kommentarer/'.$data['query']->row()->url_friendly;
$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->query($qry)->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = $per_page;
$config['uri_segment'] = 3; //this is dependent to where your page number displays in url

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

$qry .= " limit {$per_page} offset {$offset} ";
$data['result'] = $this->db->query($qry)->result();

$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code after u done proper changes.........
There is an inbuilt Pagination class provided by codeIgniter. You can find it in user guide.

Define a start index variable in the function where u want to use pagination as zero.

```
  public function pagination($start_index = 0)
   {

     $result = $this->model->get_results($data); //this $data is the argument which you are passing to your model function. If you are using database to get results array.

     $items_per_page = 10;   //this is constant variable which you need to define

      $filtered_result = array_splice($result, $start_index, ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS);

     $model['$filtered_result'] = $filtered_result;

     $total_rows = count($result);

     $model['page_links'] = create_page_links (base_url()."/controlelr_name/pagination",ITEM_PER_PAGE_USERS, $total_rows);

     $this->load->view('controller_name/view_file_name', $model);
 }

    function create_page_links($base_url, $per_page, $total_rows) {

      $CI = & get_instance();
      $CI->load->library('pagination');

      $config['base_url'] = $base_url;
      $config['total_rows'] = $total_rows;
      $config['per_page'] = $per_page; 

      $CI->pagination->initialize($config); 

      return $CI->pagination->create_links();
   }
```

This create page links function is a generic function.............for more explanation check pagination class from user guide......

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as jml from comments");
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $row = $row->jml;
    } // to count all result in your table


    $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'comments/index/'; // set the base url for pagination
    $config['total_rows'] = $row; // total rows
    $config['per_page'] = '10'; // the number of per page for pagination
    $config['uri_segment'] = 3; // see from base_url. 3 for this case
    $config['first_link'] = 'Awal';
    $config['last_link'] = 'Akhir';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Selanjutnya';
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Sebelumnya';
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['comments'] = $this->MArtikel->getAllCommentsPagination($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
    // end pagination
```